# Is it possible to use a Class as AsyncTask parameters?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm using a class that contains `AsyncTask` to get **JSON** from my server which return different types of variables that vary depending on the situation (sometimes it return `String`, sometimes `Bool` etc). So what I'm trying to achieve is that to use the same class but changing the `onPostExecute()` return value depending on the situation.

If my script return `Bool`, the result changes to `Boolean` etc.  I would like to know is it possible to pass a class as parameters in `AsynTask` method in Java? Or if there are any other better alternatives? Thanks in advance.

```
public class PHPConnecteur extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, myClass>{

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final myClass result) {
    //do something
  }

}
```

Comment: Make the parameter as Object
`@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final Object result) {
    //do something
  }`
then you can check the class type using  instanceOf

Comment: Maybe generic will work for you?

Comment: Either make it an Object and check the type at runtime, or create a union class and use that-  which will end up doing pretty much the same thing.

Comment: *sometimes it return String, sometimes Bool*.. By this, do you mean that you have separate methods on the server that return a String or a Bool. If not, do you mean you have a single method on the server that you call that can either return a Bool or a String??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear. You have specified that you will get **JSON** from your server and it should return response in JSON format.

What do you mean the return types are vary sometimes?

If the values for the keys are vary in response JSON, then you convert the response String to JSON object and check for the appropriate data type like,

```
Object obj = jsonObject.get("some_key");
if (obj.getClass().equals(Boolean.class) {
    // do your operation
}
// other checks goes here
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm searching for..sorry for the bad explanation btw

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but the problem is the Listener, if you have one it should be like:

```
public class PHPConnecteur<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, T>{
  Listener<T> executedListener;
  //set executedListener in constructor

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final T result) {
       executedListener.on(result);
  }
}
```

So you can call as with:

```
 new PHPConnecteur<String>(new Listener<String>() {
       void on(String result) {
            //do with result
       }
   });
```

But still, the result of the asynctask will have to be cast to T with simply return (T) result at doInBackground, and there's no simply way to cast it to a correctly type instead of doing all those type checks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to pass an Object as a parameter and then on onPostExecute (Object object) see what kind of Class your object is with the following example:

```
 private static class PHPConnecteur extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
        Boolean aBoolean = false;
        return aBoolean;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object object) {

        if (object.getClass().equals(Boolean.class)) {
            //do something
        } else if (object.getClass().equals(Integer.class)) {
            //do something
        } else if (object.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
            //do something
        } //etc
```

and consult for each type of class.

```
        Boolean.class;
        Character.class;
        Byte.class;
        Short.class;
        Integer.class;
        Long.class;
        Float.class;
        Double.class;
        Void.class;
```